# Why does Play 2.3 application give me "Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]" at startup with MySQL setup in application.conf?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I have created a test Play 2.3 application with the help of `activator` and the `play-scala` template:

```
activator new test play-scala
```

This is **build.sbt**:

```
name := """test"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 jdbc,
 anorm,
 cache,
 ws
)
```

In **application.conf** I've set up MySQL to be the database for the application:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*******?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password="********"
```

When I type `activator run` in console it starts the server on localhost and the port 9999 just fine. However, when I open the application in my browser I get the following error:

```
Configuration error
Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the mysql driver to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. Could you also tell what then "jdbc" dependency gives me if not he mysql connector?

Comment: I just thought that "jdbc" dependency itself will fetch the connector as well. But thinking it deeper I understand now that jdbc is just a DB layer protocol and there could be different connectors.

Comment: Exactly. Nowadays, jdbc is part of the jdk so it does not add anything. The classes can be found in java.sql and javax.sql.